# Configure ESLint with TypeScript in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am trying to configure ESLint in Visual Studio 2019, I enabled ESLint in Options and I have installed ESLint 7.4.0 in node_modules inside my project, which should cause Visual Studio to use that version according to [this document](https://github.com/microsoft/JSTSdocs/blob/master/articles/editor/linting.md). But this causes a single not so helpful error.

When running `eslint .` in the command line from the same directory as the `.eslintrc.yml` file it works and errors and warnings about my code are reported.

When viewing a `.js`, `.ts` or `.tsx` file in Visual Studio it reports the following error `internal-error: (ESLint) Unexpected token {` at the first character of the file. No other errors are reported (where the command line does report errors). Visual Studio does report the usual intellisense TypeScript errors in these files.

[image: Error in Visual Studio 2019]

The following is my .eslintrc.yml file.

```
---
parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser" # Specifies the ESLint parser
parserOptions:
    ecmaFeatures:
        jsx: true # Allows for the parsing of JSX
settings:
    react:
        version: detect # Tells eslint-plugin-react to automatically detect the version of React to use
extends:
    - plugin:react/recommended # Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    - plugin:react-hooks/recommended # Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react-hooks
    - plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended # Uses the recommended rules from the @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
```

Is there a way to see what Visual Studio is executing and what causes this error?

I tried running `devenv.exe /log`, but this logged nothing interesting, only that something was done with eslint. As you can see below.

```
821  Begin export of category 'TypeScript_EsLint' ({d5d56c12-87c4-46f2-894f-3a75ee781f48}) from package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' ({2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}). 3095452 KB of virtual memory currently available.   Profile manager 2020/08/19 08:11:21.001 
822  End export of category 'TypeScript_EsLint' ({d5d56c12-87c4-46f2-894f-3a75ee781f48}) from package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript.TypeScriptPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.TypeScript, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral' ({2FFE45C4-5C73-493C-B187-F2E955FF875E}). 3095452 KB of virtual memory currently available.   Profile manager 2020/08/19 08:11:21.003
```

Comment: This is this issue on Microsoft Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1109947/local-install-of-eslint-breaks-in-editor-linting.html

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the exact same problem, and thanks to the article linked from the comment by @Qurben, I solved it by:

1. Downgrade to ESLint 6.8, since ESLint 7 requires Node.js 12, and older versions of Visual Studio 2019 run Node.js 8. This may not be necessary any longer.
2. Add `parserOptions.tsconfigRootDir = __dirname` to .eslintrc.js (as seen in [this instruction](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/TYPED_LINTING.md). Note that this probably doesn't work in .eslintrc.yml or .eslintrc.json.